# Word 2010 additional file format

Tags: ms-word, word-2010

I'm not sure whether this is the best approach for this or whether I perhaps should ask the question more clearer.

What I want to do is to create an additional file output - e.g. if the user uses Word to create a description consisting of known tags, I want to be able to save this as bbcode.

Now I do have an idea of how to do this, but is there a way to say add another file format to the "Save file"-dialog box and have it run a parser and file writer, that'd read the current document and export it using known bbcode-tags (that perhaps would be adjustable from some configuration window)?

The result would be a file containing bbcode as well as the text information that the user has entered.

How would I hook up my addin to the file output dialog? Is there a way to do this? I'm not sure it's custom XML since I won't be using the XML at all.

Thanks in advance and please excuse my poor English.

Edit: after having a look at the Word 2010 AddIn-project, I figured, that I'm looking for a way to define my own "export"-format. I'd like to export the BBCode to a .txt (or even .bbcode) file. The Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat seems to have its own fixed enumeration. Is there a way to add an export-format?

Comment: You can write a text converter, but there are two sorts now and I only know anything about the older one. In the older converter mechanism, Word sends RTF to a Win32 DLL (not a COM DLL) in chunks using a callback mechanism. Your converter would have to convert the RTF into whatever format you wanted. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/111716  . The second arrived with Word 2007 SP1 or 2 I think, and uses a COM interface. I think in that case Word sends OOXML format and you have to translate that. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd300649(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: The other thing you may be able to do is intercept the FileSave command and write your format using standard file write commands (either the ones in VBA, or the ones in the FileSystemObject). A lot depends on what exactly your format needs to be.

Comment: To be honest I want to save a text file (or show the converted text) with BBCode in a manner that you could open it and copy-paste into a forum post. I think it's more difficult to handle the proper selection of the tags though (that'S what I'm currently working on). Thanks for the help though :).

Comment: Thank you - if you put that as a separate comment reply, I'll mark it as the answer to my question as this is basically what I will take as the base to convert formatted text to bbcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some code for this here:

phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=395554